# How to get the original string in the TipTap editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to do xss protect processing on the backend(used this library
https://github.com/naver/lucy-xss-filter).
But it has a problem.
My front is made with vue.js and I am using tiptap as an editor. Problem is This editor automatically convert characters like ?, &, /, <, >.
So, when I convert in the backend, it is converted twice.
As a policy issue, the conversion must be done in the backend.
Is there a way to get the original unconverted string from the tiptap editor?

vue : 2.6.11
tiptap-vuetify : 2.24.0

Comment: You can use blur event listener to convert the encoded text to the original text. Refer here: https://tiptap.dev/api/events#blur